# Change JCheckBox state only if password is correct

Tags: java, jcheckbox

Here what I would like to code:
When operator clicks on JCheck box, it opens a JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog. If the password is correct, then JCheckbox can change its state.
If password is not correct, it won't.
How can I do that?

I've added ActionListener to the checkbox, but the state changes everytime, never mind the password.

Thanks

```
cb.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) ->
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (LoginAsRoot())
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            for (JCheckBox cblist : TestSequenceCheckboxList)
                            {
                                if (!cblist.isSelected())
                                    TestSequenceToPerform.set(i, "null");
                                else
                                    TestSequenceToPerform.set(i, cblist.getText());

                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            cb.setSelected(true);

                        MainFrame.repaint();
                        MainFrame.pack();
                    }
                    catch (HeadlessException ex)
                    {
                        Utilities.Functions.PopUp_Message(evt.toString() + " " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: The 'LoginAsRoot()' function returns to result of the password query.

Comment: I tried to force the checkbox to selected if password is not correct, but it doesn't work.